# Как передать значение в функцию?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

Как правильно передать значение **`D`** в функцию `retranslateUi`, как это можно осуществить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/Мои документы/Загрузки/Музыка/Монтажная-область-1.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, -10, 451, 101))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 127);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.nazvanie = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.nazvanie.setEnabled(True)
        self.nazvanie.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 400, 30))
        self.nazvanie.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 0))
        self.nazvanie.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.nazvanie.setFont(font)
        self.nazvanie.setObjectName("nazvanie")
        self.primer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.primer.setEnabled(True)
        self.primer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 400, 40))
        self.primer.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 0))
        self.primer.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.primer.setFont(font)
        self.primer.setObjectName("primer")
        self.a_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.a_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 107, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.a_rav.setFont(font)
        self.a_rav.setObjectName("a_rav")
        self.b_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.b_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 157, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.b_rav.setFont(font)
        self.b_rav.setObjectName("b_rav")
        self.c_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.c_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 207, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.c_rav.setFont(font)
        self.c_rav.setObjectName("c_rav")
        self.vvod_a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_a.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_a.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_a.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_a.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_a.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_a.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_a.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.vvod_a.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.vvod_a.setObjectName("vvod_a")
        self.vvod_c = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_c.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 210, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_c.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_c.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_c.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_c.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_c.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_c.setObjectName("vvod_c")
        self.vvod_b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_b.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_b.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_b.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_b.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_b.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_b.setObjectName("vvod_b")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 100, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(91, 91, 15, 166))
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_2.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.btn_resh = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_resh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.btn_resh.setFont(font)
        self.btn_resh.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_resh.setObjectName("btn_resh")
        self.btn_resh.clicked.connect(self.Knopka)
        self.resh_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.resh_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-200, 110, 94, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.resh_text.setFont(font)
        self.resh_text.setObjectName("resh_text")
        self.vvod_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 230, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.vvod_text.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_text.setObjectName("vvod_text")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.error_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.error_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-310, 100, 230, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.error_text.setFont(font)
        self.error_text.setObjectName("error_text")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.dis = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dis.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-200, 110, 94, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.dis.setFont(font)
        self.dis.setObjectName("dis")
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def Knopka(self):
        if self.vvod_a.text() != '' and self.vvod_b.text() != '' and self.vvod_c.text() != '':
            try:
                a = int(self.vvod_a.text())
                b = int(self.vvod_b.text())
                c = int(self.vvod_c.text())
                D = b*b - 4*a*c #---ЭТО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ НУЖНО
                print(str(D))
                self.vvod_text.move(-310, 100)
                self.resh_text.move(110, 100)
            except:
                error = QMessageBox()
                error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
                error.setText("Введены некорректные значения!")
                error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
                error.exec_()
        else:
            a = str(self.vvod_a.text())
            b = str(self.vvod_b.text())
            c = str(self.vvod_c.text())
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            error.setText("Введены не все значения!")
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            if a == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение a!')
                error.exec_()
            elif b == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение b!')
                error.exec_()
            elif c == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение c!')
                error.exec_()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Решатель квадратных уравнений"))
        self.nazvanie.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Решатель квадратных уравнений</p></body></html>"))
        self.primer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">x²+bx+c=0</p></body></html>"))
        self.a_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "а="))
        self.b_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b="))
        self.c_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c="))
        self.btn_resh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решить!"))
        self.resh_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение:"))
        self.vvod_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите коофиценты..."))
        self.error_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверьте ввод!"))
        self.dis.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D = b²-4ac\nD = " + D))#---НУЖНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ СЮДА

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:/Мои документы/Загрузки/Музыка/Монтажная-область-1.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, -10, 451, 101))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 127);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.nazvanie = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.nazvanie.setEnabled(True)
        self.nazvanie.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 400, 30))
        self.nazvanie.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 0))
        self.nazvanie.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.nazvanie.setFont(font)
        self.nazvanie.setObjectName("nazvanie")
        self.primer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.primer.setEnabled(True)
        self.primer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 400, 40))
        self.primer.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 0))
        self.primer.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.primer.setFont(font)
        self.primer.setObjectName("primer")
        self.a_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.a_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 107, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.a_rav.setFont(font)
        self.a_rav.setObjectName("a_rav")
        self.b_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.b_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 157, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.b_rav.setFont(font)
        self.b_rav.setObjectName("b_rav")
        self.c_rav = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.c_rav.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 207, 26, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.c_rav.setFont(font)
        self.c_rav.setObjectName("c_rav")
        self.vvod_a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_a.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_a.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_a.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_a.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_a.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_a.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_a.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.vvod_a.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.vvod_a.setObjectName("vvod_a")
        self.vvod_c = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_c.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 210, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_c.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_c.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_c.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_c.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_c.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_c.setObjectName("vvod_c")
        self.vvod_b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.vvod_b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 41, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.vvod_b.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_b.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.vvod_b.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.vvod_b.setMaxLength(3)
        self.vvod_b.setFrame(True)
        self.vvod_b.setObjectName("vvod_b")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 100, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(91, 91, 15, 166))
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_2.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.btn_resh = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_resh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.btn_resh.setFont(font)
        self.btn_resh.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.btn_resh.setObjectName("btn_resh")
        
#-        self.btn_resh.clicked.connect(self.Knopka)
        
        self.resh_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.resh_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-200, 180, 94, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.resh_text.setFont(font)
        self.resh_text.setObjectName("resh_text")
        self.vvod_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.vvod_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 230, 31))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.vvod_text.setFont(font)
        self.vvod_text.setObjectName("vvod_text")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.error_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.error_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-310, 100, 230, 31))
#        self.error_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 300, 230, 61))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.error_text.setFont(font)
        self.error_text.setObjectName("error_text")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.dis = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        
#        self.dis.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-200, 210, 94, 31))
        self.dis.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 210, 94, 61))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.dis.setFont(font)
        self.dis.setObjectName("dis")
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Решатель квадратных уравнений"))
        self.nazvanie.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Решатель квадратных уравнений</p></body></html>"))
        self.primer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">x²+bx+c=0</p></body></html>"))
        self.a_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "а="))
        self.b_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b="))
        self.c_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c="))
        self.btn_resh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решить!"))
        self.resh_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение:"))
        self.vvod_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите коофиценты..."))
#        self.error_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверьте ввод!"))

# -        self.dis.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D = b²-4ac\nD = " + D))#---НУЖНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ СЮДА


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn_resh.clicked.connect(self.knopka)
        
    def knopka(self):
        a = self.vvod_a.text()
        b = self.vvod_b.text()
        c = self.vvod_c.text()
        
        if a and b and c:
            try:
                a = int(a)
                b = int(b)
                c = int(c)
                D = b * b - (4 * a * c)                    # ЭТО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ НУЖНО
                print(str(D))
#                self.vvod_text.move(-310, 100)
#
                self.vvod_text.hide()
                self.resh_text.show()                
                self.resh_text.move(110, 180)
                                                           # НУЖНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ СЮДА
                self.dis.setText(f"D = b²-4ac\nD = {D}")   # !!! +++ 

            except:
                error = QMessageBox()
                error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
                error.setText("Введены некорректные значения!")
                error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
                error.exec_()
        else:
#            a = str(self.vvod_a.text())
#            b = str(self.vvod_b.text())
#            c = str(self.vvod_c.text())

# +++
            self.dis.clear()
            self.resh_text.hide()
            self.vvod_text.show()

            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            error.setText("Введены не все значения!")
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            if a == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение a!')
                error.exec_()
            elif b == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение b!')
                error.exec_()
            elif c == '':
                error.setDetailedText('Отсутствует значение c!')
                error.exec_()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я новичок, особенно в тематике ООП. После вопроса сам убедился в своей глупости.

Comment: @the_sterres пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно переменную D сделать глобальной в функции где задаётся значение переменной и в функции куда нужно передать значение переменной:

```
def Knopka(self):
        if self.vvod_a.text() != '' and self.vvod_b.text() != '' and self.vvod_c.text() != '':
            try:
                global D
                a = int(self.vvod_a.text())
                b = int(self.vvod_b.text())
                c = int(self.vvod_c.text())
                D = b*b - 4*a*c #---ЭТО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ НУЖНО
                print(str(D))
                self.vvod_text.move(-310, 100)
                self.resh_text.move(110, 100)
```

᠌᠌ ᠌

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        global D
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Решатель квадратных уравнений"))
        self.nazvanie.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Решатель квадратных уравнений</p></body></html>"))
        self.primer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">x²+bx+c=0</p></body></html>"))
        self.a_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "а="))
        self.b_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b="))
        self.c_rav.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c="))
        self.btn_resh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решить!"))
        self.resh_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение:"))
        self.vvod_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите коофиценты..."))
        self.error_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверьте ввод!"))
        self.dis.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D = b²-4ac\nD = " + D))#---НУЖНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ СЮДА
```

Comment: К сожалению, я так пробовал, бесполезно...